# Different Portrait and Landscape layouts with VideoView playing

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, android-videoview, portrait

I have a VideoView taking up the whole screen when in Landscape.
I want to be able to constrain the video to the top half of the screen when in portrait so I can show additional controls/info below it.

I'm using "configChanges=orientation" in the manifest to prevent the videoview from restarting when the orientation changes. However this means the different orientation layouts are ignored and only the first one encountered used.

Does anyone have any idea how I would go about keeping the video playing between changes from Portrait to Landscape and back while in Portrait displaying additional UI components below the video?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain your data playing in videoview from restarting when orientation takes place:

1. Override the onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method to return the object you would like to retain.
2. When your activity is created again, call getLastNonConfigurationInstance() to recover your object.

you can also refer this doc:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: `Caution: While you can return any object, you should never pass an object that is tied to the Activity, such as a Drawable, an Adapter, a View or any other object that's associated with a Context.`

Doesn't look like i can simply retain the video view.

Comment: yes ...you need to save the situation on your video file that how much it is being played before orientation ...